# ListViewItem Drag&Drop Operation Stuck

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

During the drag&drop operation of listviewitems in an normal UWP ListView sometimes the windows sharing crashes

The item down is stuck there until I decide to close the app (with the "is being used for sharing popup") - **In fact it seems like the Windows Explorer does not allow *any* drag&drop operations until the app closes!**

From my debugging I can see that the **DragEnter** gets fired but there is no **DragItemsCompleted**

### [image: New App]

**How to replicate this issue**

1. Create a new UWP app

   - TargetAPI: 1803
   - MinAPI: 1803
2. Create a ListView

```xml
<ListView CanDragItems="True">
    <ListView.Items>
        <ListViewItem>asdf</ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>asdf</ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>asdf</ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>asdfEx</ListViewItem>
    </ListView.Items>
</ListView>
```

3. Quickly drag the item and release it on top of the listview
   3.1 Sometimes it gets stuck immediately, sometimes it takes more attempts

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue on 1809 when I set target and min to 1803. What's your OS version? Can you update to 1809 to test? When I was working on 1803 and set the target to 1803, I don't remember that I have this kind of issue. So it might be a specific problem on your device? If you have another device, would you mind to also give it a test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a specific windows 1803 bug - pressing escape seems to unblock the UI.

Nothing I have tried in the code behind seems to be working...

Answer (score 0):

Possible error (without seeing more code..) :you dont capture mouse, so your application doesnt detect your up event

see [mouse.capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.mouse.capture?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#overloads)

maybe for UWP see [UIElement.CapturePointer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.capturepointer)

Comment: Thanks for your answer - this is a new project with no code behind - the only modification made is this listview.

Comment: From what I could see pressing escape and then clicking seems to reset the sharing back to where I can drag&drop, but I cannot ask my users to do that every time the app gets stuck

Comment: i am not in WIN10.. i cant replicate but if you capture the mouse just after the dragenter the problem will be resolved  and you release the mouse after the mouse up event

Answer (score 0):

I may have found an answer (at least it is working for me for now). I was previously triggering the `DragStarting` using the following code:

```
Private Async Sub brdPlayer_PointerPressed(sender As Object, e As PointerRoutedEventArgs)
    Await CType(sender, Border).StartDragAsync(e.GetCurrentPoint(CType(sender, Border)))
End Sub
```

However, this was causing `DragStarting` to be triggered twice (and possibly other stuff), so when I modified the code by adding:

```
e.Handled = True
```

I am still testing the other scenarios to make sure this really fixes the whole thing, but hopefully it helps you as well!